# Get all virtual goods in a category and their prices with Soomla

Tags: unity-game-engine, soomla

I bet this is simple, but I can't seem to find a way to get all virtual goods in a specific category.
Also, how to get a virtual good price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the price:

```
PurchasableVirtualItem purchaseableVirtualItem = StoreInfo
    .GetPurchasableItemWithProductId (MyGameStore.NO_ADS_UNLOCK_ALL_PRODUCT_ID);

float unlockAllPrice = ((PurchaseWithMarket)purchaseableVirtualItem.PurchaseType)
    .MarketItem
    .MarketPriceAndCurrency;
```

You declare the category yourself, so you already have access to all IDs in it, see this example:

```
public static VirtualCategory GENERAL_CATEGORY = new VirtualCategory (
        "General", new List<string> (new string[] {
        NO_ADS_LIFETIME_PRODUCT_ID,
        NO_ADS_UNLOCK_ALL_PRODUCT_ID,
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks @carlos-rodriguez! Is the MarketPriceAndCurrency available even if offline?

Comment: when you specify your goods in the Assets class, you also specify a price. that price is for times of no connectivity. that was the initial intent.